# Prolog: String to List

Tags: string, list, prolog, xsb

I have a string that I want to convert to a list:

```
"a + b = c"
```

I need it in list format to pass it onto to a member rule. When I pass it onto the member rule directly, it passes as a series of numbers which I assume is their character code, but I want the actual characters instead. How do I make it into a list then use it with a rule. I'm a novice in Prolog so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The list of numbers are (as you assumed) "character codes", or just "codes". What you want are probably one-character atoms, or "chars". Look in the documentation for predicates that convert between these.

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog has string_chars/2, but you can obtain the same using 2 ISO conforming predicates

```
?- atom_codes(A, "a + b = c"), atom_chars(A, Cs).
A = 'a + b = c',
Cs = [a, ' ', +, ' ', b, ' ', =, ' ', c].
```